# SQL Rows to Columns with only two columns

Tags: sql, pivot, rows

This question has been asked for many times but I can not relate any of the answers I have read so far to my exact question. Let us say that my original table has 2 columns.

```
Brand      Type
Mercedes   Sedan
BMW        Sedan
Mercedes   SUV
Jeep       SUV
VW         Sedan
VW         Small Family
```

I want to format the original table like the following

```
[Sedan]    [SUV]       [Small Family]
BMW        Mercedes    VW    
Mercedes   Jeep        NULL   
VW         NULL        NULL
```

Is this possible with any sort of SQL in any sort of environment (i.e. SQL server, Oracle, DB2), with or without PIVOT function?

Comment: Regardless the method you use to pivot (pivot table operator, case statement) There is no problem in pivoting the rows into columns, but the problem is that you need a third column to apply the pivot, so you need to generate a row number for example so that you can get only three rows and eliminate the null values and that is different from RDBMS to another.

Comment: @lollified is it serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, the easiest way to do that is to use `PIVOT`. , If you want to make the rows into columnar form, or columns to form as rows, the solution is only `PIVOT`.

SQL Server has a `PIVOT` function that you can use to achieve that, this link can help you: [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

**EDIT:**

***PIVOT sample:***

```
    SELECT [Sedan], [SUV], [Small Familiy] FROM
        (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY [TYPE] ORDER BY Brand) RowNum, Brand, [Type] FROM tblCar
        ) AS src
        PIVOT 
        (
            MIN(Brand) FOR [Type] IN ([Sedan], [SUV], [Small Familiy])
        ) AS pvt
```

[SQL Fiddle sample for PIVOT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc78a/1/%22SQL%20Fiddle%20Sample%20for%20PIVOT%22%22)

Hope this helps.

Comment: ***`PIVOT` is not the only way***, for example you can pivot using `case` statement.

Comment: All the examples I've seen so for on PIVOT tables use a column like an ID or whatnot and convert rows to columns for each ID. For my case, I don't have such a column for a reference.. Do you have any examples for my current case?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal , my bad, what i mean is **easiest** , post already modified. Thanks :)

Comment: @lollified you can use the `MAX or MIN` function of SQL for strings if you dont have `ID`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
    (CASE Type = 'Sedan' 
        then Brand 
        else null 
    end) Sedan, 
    (CASE Type = 'SUV' 
        then Brand 
        else null 
    end) SUV, 
    (CASE Type = 'Small Family' 
        then Brand 
        else null 
    end) SmallFamily 
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Brand varchar(8), Type varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Brand, Type)
VALUES
    ('Mercedes', 'Sedan'),
    ('BMW', 'Sedan'),
    ('Mercedes', 'SUV'),
    ('Jeep', 'SUV'),
    ('VW', 'Sedan'),
    ('VW', 'Small Family')
;


Select [Sedan],[SUV],[Small Family] FROM (
select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY TYPE)RN,Brand, Type from @Table1)T
PIVOT (
MAX(brand) FOR TYPE IN ([Sedan],[SUV],[Small Family]))P
```

Comment: for clarity, this works perfectly. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
select Sedan, SUV, [Small Family]
from
(
  select ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY TYPE ORDER BY TYPE)RN,Brand, Type from Cars)Cars
pivot
(
  max(Brand)
  for [Type] in (Sedan, SUV, [Small Family])
) piv;
```